# How to search in array column with multi values in postgresql rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

i have two two models `post`, `tags` and i want to get post where some tags.

- tag.rb

```
post_id  integer  3
tags     array  {'v1', 'v2'}
```

when search in tag model work `Tag.where('tag && array[['v1', 'v2']]')`

but when add this in post not work `Post.where('tags.tags && array[['v1', 'v2']]')`

every post has one tag

Comment: You're using an `array` on the `Post` model to store an array of `Tag` identifiers so that you can associate tags with posts, is that correct? If so, why not use associations?

Comment: Post has_one tag already what's you why not use association

Comment: Sorry, I misread and misunderstood. It looks like `Post` has one `Tag` and a `Tag` stores an array of `tags`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct/raw way to do this would be something like this:

```rb
Post.joins(:tags).where("ARRAY['v1', 'v2'] <@ tags.tags")
```

Obligatory warning about injecting user-inputted values into strings sent to a database, for the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thanks @kache i try your solution work but when use dynamic value not work `" ARRAY#{tags} && tags.tags"
`

Comment: If `tags.to_s` doesn't output something serialized in the form `['v1', 'v2']`, then that won't work. You're also using the wrong operator.

Comment: i know must tags array for example `" ARRAY[\"v1\"] <@ tags.tags"
`

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "v1" does not exist

Comment: Again, `['v1']` is not the same as `["v1"]`. Use single quotes: `['v1', 'v2']`

Comment: problem i get value like `"v1,v2"` and split it by `,`  `["v1","v2"]`

Comment: That's a different question altogether. You'll be able to find answers if you look up: "string interpolation, ruby, single double quotes"

Comment: i try send values like "['v1']" and work i think that's correct . Thanks @Kache